# Use multiple response filters in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, filter, httpresponse

is there any way to use multiple response filters in ASP.NET?

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Filter = MyFilter1
HttpContext.Current.Response.Filter = MyFilter2
```

This code is clear, can't work. It overrides the current filter with the new instance.

So, what are your best practice for this scenario.

Thank and best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only a single response filter can be applied, so you need to aggregate all the work in this filter. [Here's an example](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/RemovingWhiteSpacesAspNet.aspx) how this could be achieved:

```
Response.Filter = new TrimStream(new CompressStream(Response.Filter));
```

This way you can combine multiple streams.

Answer (score 2):

A filter is a Stream that writes to another Stream. Usually you construct a filter like this:

```
response.Filter = new MyStream(response.Filter);
```

To use multiple filters, you do the same:

```
response.Filter = new FirstFilterStream(response.Filter);
response.Filter = new SecondFilterStream(response.Filter);
```

Comment: Thanks! This solution works in context, where i don't know all filters in each module.